# TypeInitializationException in Initialize Component Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
namespace FBLALibraryApp2
{
public partial class GenrePage : ContentPage
{

    public GenrePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.ItemsSource = DataStorage.GenreList;
    }

    private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    async private void listView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GenreGroup)
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new GenreView((GenreGroup)e.Item));
    }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for a page that I have made in Xamarin. It is a simple page that displays a list of GenreGroup's. It has worked fine in the past, but recently, when I changed my code initializing the list, the application would run to a blank screen. So, I paused debugging and saw it was stuck at, initially, listView.ItemSource = DataStorage.GenreList;. Upon hitting continue, the application would throw a TypeInitializationException. I was worried that perhaps the most recent version of my code was not being built (this has happened to me before with Fast Deployment enabled), so I added a Debug.log("x"); before the troublesome line to ensure that the most recent code was being run. Upon doing this, the application began freezing on InitializeComponent() and throwing the same exception. I am stumped here as to what to do. Here is the code for where I declare the list:

```
public static class DataStorage
{
    public static List<Book> AllBookList = new List<Book> { new Book { Title = "Harry Potter", Author = "J.K. Rowling", Summary="lorem ipsum dolorum sdjfa;dklfja;dkfj;akdfja;dfjkaf", Genre= new string[] { "Fantasy", "Adventure" }, pubYear="2017" }, new Book { Title = "The Hunger Games", Author = "Suzanne Collins", Summary = "lorem ipsum dolorum sdjfa;dklfja;dkfj;akdfja;dfjkaf", Genre = new string[] { "Sci-Fi" }, pubYear = "2017" }, new Book { Title = "Thief in the Night", Author = "Jack Nimble", Summary = "lorem ipsum dolorum sdjfa;dklfja;dkfj;akdfja;dfjkaf", Genre = new string[] { "Mystery"}, pubYear = "2017" }, new Book { Title = "Hardy Bros.", Author = "Johnny Heather", Summary = "lorem ipsum dolorum sdjfa;dklfja;dkfj;akdfja;dfjkaf", Genre = new string[] { "Mystery", "Comedy" }, pubYear = "2017" } };
    public static List<GenreGroup> GenreList = new List<GenreGroup> { new GenreGroup("Mystery", "jd;akfjd;"), new GenreGroup("Fantasy", "dja;fdjkl") };
    public static GenreGroup Mystery = new GenreGroup("Mystery","djfsldfjldjF");
    public static GenreGroup Fantasy = new GenreGroup("Fantasy", "djfsldfjldjF");

    static DataStorage()
    {
        foreach (Book book in AllBookList)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < book.Genre.Length; x++)
            {
                if (book.Genre[x] == "Mystery")
                {
                    Mystery.Add(book);
                }
                else if (book.Genre[x] == "Fantasy")
                {
                    Fantasy.Add(book);
                }

            }
        }
        GenreList = new List<GenreGroup> { Mystery, Fantasy };
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue is somewhere in this code, as this is what I changed. Note: I understand that my code right now is a little strange and I define GenreList explicitly, and then redefine it later, but I was trying to ensure it wasn't null for whatever reason. Thanks for any help

Update: upon placing Debug.WriteLine BEFORE InitializeComponent, it now freezes on Debug.WriteLIne and throws the same, TypeInitializationEXception

Update: Here is the code for GenreGroup and Book

```
public class GenreGroup : List<Book>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public GenreGroup(string title, string description)
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string[] subjectHeadings { get; set; }
    public string[] Genre { get; set; }
    public string pubYear { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does DataStorage come initialized ? Or null ?

Comment: Are the properties `Title` and `Description` from `GenreGroup` static ?

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Have you try my solution? Please leave a comment if you do something, thanks.

Comment: @Greggz the properties Title and Description are not static because GenreGroup is not a static class (there are many different Genres and thus many different GenreGroup objects I want to create). Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by initialized or null. If you could explain further that would be great. I was under the impression that if you had a static class, you needn't call it or initialize it but perhaps I am mistaken?

Comment: @user65909 You need to initialize `Mistery` and `Fantasy` first ..

Comment: @user65909 Show us class `GenreGroup`. If you initialize properly `Mistery` and `Fantasy` your code is write, at least inside `static constructor`

Comment: @user65909 And the class Book while we're at it :)

Comment: @Greggz I think I have initialized Mystery and Fantasy by making it public static GenreGroup Mystery = new GenreGroup(...); Also, I updated my question to add in the code for GenreGroup and Book

Comment: I just run your code and I had no problems...

Comment: @Greggz well, i am seriously triggered. I cleaned my solution and built it again. then tried to run the app. It failed, but this time it said something about XamlC failing on Xamarin.iOS (which is weird bc im running android). So, I tried running the arm version of the android emulator and... it worked. Took a long time to load bc arm is slow in the emulator but it worked nonetheless. So looks like this was not a code problem, but simply a problem with visual studio or the emulator or some other BS thing like that. Looks like I got it figured out though. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You helped me out a lot, so if you wanna post that you ran my code and had no problems as an answer, ill mark it as accepted.

Comment: @user65909 Hum alright! I can say you 're missing some initializations which you really were in the beggining of the post. I will try to post a answer thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You' re missing initializations here:

```
 public static GenreGroup Mystery; // Init this
 public static GenreGroup Fantasy; // And this
```

**Edit**: I just ran your code and it's fine. Just clean your project and rebuild it. VS has plenty of bugs. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> listView.ItemsSource = DataStorage.GenreList;

This line will call `static DataStorage()`, in this static constructor, `Mystery` and `Fantasy` should be initialized before you call it. So the solution should be this:

1) Add `public GenreGroup() { }` in your `GenreGroup` class;

2) Init `Mystery` and `Fantasy` in `DataStorage` class:

```
    public static GenreGroup Mystery = new GenreGroup();
    public static GenreGroup Fantasy = new GenreGroup();
```

Comment: I followed your answer and the issue is still not resolved. It appears that the TypeInitializationException is thrown on whatever the first line is in the GenrePage() constructor, whether this be a Debug.WriteLine or InitializeComponent()

Comment: "This line will call static DataStorage()" That is incorrect. Static constructors run always before any other code.